# TSQL: Set a starting number for table IDENTITY column

Tags: t-sql

I have a temp table loaded with data like below

```
#Id    Name    Type
1      John    1
2      Wick    1
3      Mike    1
```

Then I need to insert data from another table that might have conflict of ID, so I want to set the max ID of new sets of data like below:

```
SELECT @maxId = (MAX(Id) + 1) FROM #tmpPeople

CREATE TABLE #tblUser (
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1, @maxId) -- Doesn't work for some reason, says syntax error
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    Type INT
)

INSERT INTO #tblUser
SELECT Name, Type 
FROM Users
```

After I got the data into `#tblUser`, I want to insert into `#tmpPeople` and I wish to achieve the result below:

```
#Id    Name    Type
1      John    1
2      Wick    1
3      Mike    1
4      Dank    2
5      Nora    2
6      YONG    2
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: This strikes me as an incorrect use of an identity column.  You should not be worrying about the value in the identity column, but only need to know that it will be unique and ever increasing.  If you need to generate a sequence across all records, look into using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually, identity columns are not guaranteed to be unique, and not even guaranteed to be ordered - it's quite easy to insert manual values into identity columns - and SQL Server will not stop you from inserting any value you want just because the column is marked as identity.  Having said that, I agree that identity values should carry no business meaning.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agree about the ordering, but AFAIK SQL Server will never generate an identity value which already exists in the column (though this may not prevent someone from manually inserting the same value). A

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, Yes and no. Automatically generated identity values will be unique (unless reseeded using `DBCC CHECKIDENT`). Basically, as long as you don't do anything manually with identity columns, they will be unique and ordered.